# Meaning of no explicit time dependence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

What does "no explicit time dependence" mean in this context? :

> A symmetry of the [KdV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) is given by $$\tilde x=x, \tilde t=t+\epsilon, \tilde u =u$$
>   as there is no explicit time dependence in the KdV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Physics, the notion of explicit time dependence denotes equations where the time parameter t occurs "freely" and not only as a $\frac{d}{dt}$. So an equation of the form $v(x)=a_0t+v_0$ is explicitly time dependent, but $a(x)=a_0$ is not.

Comment: Thank you, Dominik. Just to confirm my understanding of your explanation: the partial derivative wrt $t$ does not count as explicitly time-dependent, only an actual factor of $t$ in the equation does?

Comment: That's right. Another commonly used word for this is that the equation is *autonomous*, a word which for unfathomable reasons doesn't appear in the wikipedia article on differential equations.

Comment: Thank you, @HaraldHanche-Olsen !